# Efficient conversion of int to string

Tags: string, cocoa, type-conversion, string-formatting

I've seen several questions/answers here that suggest the best way to get a string representation of an integer in Objective-C is to use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]`. I'm afraid the C/C++ programmer in me is having a hard time believing I want to bring all the formatting code into play for such a simple task. That is, I assume `stringWithFormat` needs to parse through the format string looking for all the different type specifiers, field widths, and options that I could possibly use, then it has to be able to interpret that variable length list of parameters and use the format specifier to coerce `x` to the appropriate type, then go through a lengthy process of conversion, accounting for signed/unsigned values and negation along the way.

Needless to say in C/C++ I could simply use `itoa(x)` which does exactly one thing and does it extremely efficiently.

I'm not interested in arguing the relative merits of one *language* over another, but rather just asking the question: is the incredibly powerful `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", x]` *really* the most efficient way to do this very, very simple task in Objective-C? Seems like I'm cracking a peanut with a sledge hammer.

Comment: You're comparing peanuts to coconuts: `itoa()` doesn't give you an `NSString`.

Comment: do you really think it's more complex? `itoa` probably does the same signed conversion as `%d`, and my guess is it would iterate through the string copying characters as it goes and then turning the array to an `NSString`. It seems like about the same complexity to me

Comment: Then use `NSNumber` and call stringValue on it. ;)

Comment: Be sure you aren't doing a premature optimization here. How many numbers are you converting to strings? If you just need to do a few then don't worry about. Do what is easier to read and maintain. If you truly have a measured performance issue then look into optimizing the code.

Comment: or use `itoa(x)` and use C-style strings until you really need a NSString.

Comment: This is what I love about stackoverflow. Josh, `itoa()` does a similar operation without all the overhead. My question is how to get the efficiency of `itoa()` in Objective-C. Jason, you're ignoring the effort `stringWithFormat` has to make to parse the format string, and the options it has to take into account when creating the resulting string. ludesign, you're giving me an answer in a comment. maddy, you're making assumptions about *why* and *when* I'm asking my question, then pontificating about how dumb I am.

Comment: Finally, Matthias, you're missing the point of the question -- unless that's an answer, in which case it should be submitted as an answer instead of a comment. :-)

Comment: @Craig Where did I say you were dumb? Wow! I offered an honest opinion about the possibility of premature optimization. That is all. It was not in any way meant to be insulting. It's pretty sad that you took it that way.

Comment: Maddy, rather than answering my question you tried to figure out my motives, which is the problem with most answers/comments on Stackoverflow. I asked a question. If you have an answer, I'm excited and happy to hear it. If you want to question *why* I'm asking a question, assume I'm "doing it wrong", then suggest that I don't do the thing that isn't what led to my question in the first place, I'm not interested. I didn't take offense; I merely read your comment back to you in the voice that others hear when you speak. I frankly found it amusing, not offensive. :-)

Comment: It does a _similar_ operation, @Craig, but you don't end up with an object. I think a much fairer comparison would be `int` to `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `itoa()` followed by any of [`+[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-CJBGJGID) [`-[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BCIGDAHA) or [`+[NSString stringWithCString:encoding:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJCCGHJ) if it makes you feel better, but I wouldn't worry about it unless you're sure this is a performance problem.

Comment: ... or `initWithUTF8String:` to save some keystrokes :-)

Comment: Agreed. But I'm trying to be more Objective-C-ish ( == readability) while maintaining my C/C++ sensibilities about efficiency. I was finding it difficult to believe that the common suggestion (`stringWithFormat`) was really the most efficient way to do this simple task. I agree that `[NSString stringWithUTF8String:itoa(x)]` is a more efficient solution. Just requires the reader to be a C programmer and there are fewer and fewer of us around. :-)

Comment: `char *(*integer_to_ascii)(int, char *, int) = itoa;` @Craig? :P

Answer (score -1):

You could also use [description method](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description). It boxes it as `NSNumber` and converts to a `NSString`.

```
int intVariable = 1;

NSString* stringRepresentation = [@(intVariable) description];
```

Comment: The `description` method must never be used for such things. It should only be used for debugging and logging.

Comment: @rmaddy What you say is true but I am spitting out an option of course.

Comment: Even so, there is nothing efficient about your suggestion. You first create an `NSNumber` object, then you create an `NSString` using an unknown implementation that could be less efficient than simply using the `stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: I like the direction here, though. `[[NSNumber numberWithInt:x] stringValue]` has the benefit of *potentially* eliminating the format string parsing and the formatting of the result according to a very powerful format specification scheme. Assuming the underlying code doesn't just do `stringWithFormat` it has a high likelihood of being more efficient than the usual approach of using `stringWithFormat`.

Comment: @Craig Good point. However, I never tested the performances of both the options. Maybe someone else can jump in with more ideas.

Comment: @Craig, `stringValue` calls `descriptionWithLocale:` which uses `stringWithFormat:locale:`. See the docs.